# Loading data from database to widget

Tags: android, server, widget

my android application receiving data from data base on server and showing it. i did this part.
but i am trying to show that information in a widget (view flipper).
there is a button on widget for start receiving data.
i do not know where should i began!

some classes wont work in extends App Widget Provider classes
server side codes are correct . the problem is android codes.
can anyone show me an example?

```
public class appwidget extends AppWidgetProvider {



public static Typeface yekan,nazanin,koodak;

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}
```